# Is there a way to use windows keymap/keybindings with VS Code on Mac OS X?

Tags: visual-studio-code, osx-mavericks

I use a windows keyboard with my mac and the `cmd` key is mapped to my `super/windows` key. Using `ctrl+v` feels more natural in text/code editing compared to `super+v`. How can I revert to windows key bindings in VS Code?

Answer (score 10):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=smcpeak.default-keys-windows

Installing this extension did the trick.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice!

Comment: Thanks mate, this is a lifesaver! :)